# angular.js on-keyup doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I would like to make a javascript alert/call a function onkeyup.

But it doesn't work. see [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELsKA8VaUx87X9msYWEE?p=preview)

Simply:

```
<input ng-keyup="alert('hi')">
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ngKeyup` exprssion will be evaluated in the context of the current `$scope`, so everything you refer to needs to be declared on the `$scope`.

E.g.:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.alert = $window.alert.bind($window);
    // Or
    // $scope.alert = function (msg) { $window.alert(msg); }
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/H73Ap0ZtCOgc7agSO3JA?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 3):

Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions. Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.

Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like window, document or location. This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.

Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called from expressions. Such services provide mockable access to globals.

that means you should write function alert in your controller , or inject $window service and reference from it

```
angular.module('test',[]).controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.alert = function(text){
          alert(text)
        }

 })
```

[here is updated example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9qinRUsHyQwRhsTlOhGH?p=preview)

[from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that `$location` is to `window.location` what `$window` is to `window` (which not at all true).

Comment: why you thought what I meant $location is to window.location ?

Comment: And you are accessing the global state directly (using `alert()` instead of `$window.alert()`). Hurts testability :)

Comment: Because you say: _"You can't access window and location. You need to use services as `$window` and `$location`."_

Comment: did you see in my answer the sentence like this  ? :) I think you messed something :)

Comment: Quoting from your answer: _"Angular expressions do not have access to global variables like window, document or location. [...] Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called from expressions."_ I know you know what `$location` is, but I am afraid that new-comers might easily misinterpret what you are saying.

Comment: Indeed ! It doesn't mean it is not confusing though. Anyway, we've made a big deal out of it, which we shouldn't really :)

Comment: Thank you guys. Sorry I can't accept 2 answers - but I voted it up!